# MVC Core Get Controller ViewModel Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get result from Controller which calls Repository which extracts a ViewModel at the end, this is for Unit testing. The bold below is not working.

Compile error:

> IAction Result does not contain a definition for View and no extension method View accepting a first argument of type IAction Result

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(int? id)
{
    return View(await _repository.GetProductData(id));
}

var searchresult1 = await _controller.Search(5);
```

**`var modelresult = searchresult1.View.ProductName;`**

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: added compile error

Comment: Where is this written? `var searchresult1 = await _controller.Search(5);` Please show the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
var searchresult1 = await _controller.Search(5) as ViewResult;
var result = searchResult.ViewName; // this should be the value returned from the controller
```

Or you can return the result as a `ViewData.Model`. So in your controller, you can probably do something like

```
return View("Product", await _repository.GetProductData(id));
```

Then in your test you can access the viewdata.model like

```
var result = await _controller.Search(5);
var productData = (ProductData) result.ViewData.Model; // cast it to whatever class the GetProductData(5) returns
```

Option 1 works at run time as the view name is set by the framework using route data. it is not available during unit testing. Which is why setting the view name manually in the second example works

Please see more details about [MVC view model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs)

Comment: Hi For some reason option #1 is not working, but option 2 is , which is good, trying to get first way to work also,  error here  result = searchResult.ViewName;

Comment: Option 1 works at run time as the view name is set by the framework using route data. it is not available during unit testing. Which is why setting the view name manually in the second example works.